# PHP, Funciones nativas muestran errores(Lineas Rojas)

Tags: php, visual-studio

Hoy decidí abrir mis archivos php para repasar un tema y me salen en rojo todas las funciones nativas con el error : Undefined function 'La Función'.intelephense(1010) , A que se debe esto? Gracias.

```
$mensaje = 'Este es el mensaje de testing';

//Reversa
echo strrev($mensaje);
echo("<br>");

//Encontrar texto
echo strpos($mensaje, "mensaje");
echo("<br>");

//Reemplazar texto
echo str_replace("testing", "nada", $mensaje);

//Convertir a minusculas
echo strtolower($mensaje);
echo("<br>");

//Convertir a mayusculas
echo strtoupper($mensaje);
echo("<br>"); 

//Substraer cadena
echo substr($mensaje, 10 , 5);

//Remover espacios en blanco
echo trim("Hola a   a   espacios  ");
```

Comment: Hola. El código que has copiado en la pregunta está correcto siempre y cuando tengas almacenado algo en $mensaje. Por lo que si ese es todo el contenido que tienes en el fichero, debería estar dándote problema otro fichero, no este.

Comment: Me falto copiar la variable $mensaje , pero igual me sale el error en todos mis archivos , hasta de proyectos terminados.

Comment: Actualiza los plugins de VisualStudioCode, sobre todo el intelisensePhp.